# What do the parenthesis do in Java: Dollar dollar = (Dollar) object;

Tags: java, brackets

While working with Kent Becks Book *TDD by Example*, I encountered some Java Code I did not understand.

```
public boolean equals(Object object) {
    Dollar dollar= (Dollar) object;
    return amount == dollar.amount;
}
```

Could someone please explain to me what the parenthesis in `Dollar dollar= (Dollar) object;` mean?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's an [explicit typecast](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_conversion).  Basically it's saying that "although 'object' was declared with type `Object`, I know that it's actually of type `Dollar` so it's okay to assign it to the variable 'dollar'".

Without the brackets (actually, those are parenthesis, brackets look like `[]` or `<>` depending if they are "square brackets" or "angle brackets", respectively), the compiler would report an error on that line.

Comment: Thank you for the correction. English is not my native language. I'll edit the question.

Answer (score 1):

They cast the object to the type in parenthesis.

In your example, they tell java that `object` should be of type `Dollar`

Answer (score 0):

Because the `equals()` function uses the type "Object" for the `object` parameter, The `(Dollar) object` tells the dollar variable that `object` is indeed of the `Dollar` class.  As the other replies have said, the notation is called a typecast, and is used by the Java compiler to ensure that you are using the correct type when you assign one variable to another.

For what it's worth, as a novice programmer this stuff can seem very confusing, but it does start to sink in after a while.